# Difference between .run and resolve? (Angular)

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in my Angular app that downloads data from an external source, then does some basic data operations on that data before writing it to local storage.

How can I ensure that the functions of downloading the data and doing those data operations are completely done before the first view of the app is presented?

I know of .run, and I have tried experimenting with using resolve in my view configuration, which if I understand correctly means that those functions are run before the first view is compiled. But when the app runs for the first time before data has ever been written to local storage, the compilation of the first view still fails. When I then refresh the page, everything works as expected. This leads me to believe that the run or resolve functions aren't completely finished before the app continues with rendering the first view.

Comment: Run is the first time angular bootstrap. Resolve happens before the route is resolved.

Comment: So both just start the functions, but don't wait until they complete, right?

Comment: **.run** kickstart the app and happens after the injector is created, its useful for declaring global variables with $rootScope. In the other hand **.resolve** is part of the routes module and its useful for resolve certain conditions before render the view.

Comment: Take a look at [Route Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and the resolve parameter.

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried ?

Comment: Unfortunately the app has gotten a bit complicated.. I can't even get a Codepen going properly. This is a fragment: http://codepen.io/squrler/pen/GxBKl

Basically: 
1. The app starts, loads the StorageHandler module, then checks _.json. 
2. If the timestamp in _.json is newer than the one that's already stored in localstorage, then it downloads content.json.
3. It stringifies content.json and stores it in localstorage.

Problem is when localstorage is empty the first time the app loads, it breaks. I'm guessing because localstorage is not ready yet, because the next time I refresh it works.

Comment: I don't see anything breaking. Could you reproduce the issue in the codepen ? There is no such thing as `localStorage not being ready` (unless you mean that the data is not saved yet). It is hard to make anything out with all that code (and no actual issue to observe), but it sounds like you are doing some asynchronous operations - so you need to use promises.